# SAPUI5 : Select Line item in Table not working

Tags: sapui5

I have built an XML fragment like below.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <Dialog stretch="false" title="Select User" showHeader="true">
    <content>

      <fb:FilterBar reset="onReset" search="onSearch"
        advancedMode="true">

        <fb:filterItems>
        <fb:FilterItem id="searchField" name="userSeacrch">
        <fb:control>
      <SearchField width="100%" id="searchUser" showSearchButton="false"/>
    </fb:control>
    </fb:FilterItem>
    </fb:filterItems>


      <fb:filterGroupItems>
        <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" id="fname1" idgroupTitle="Group1" name="A" label="First Name" labelTooltip="First Name">
          <fb:control>
            <Input type="Text" id="fname"/>
          </fb:control>
        </fb:FilterGroupItem>
        <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" id="lname1" groupTitle="Group1" name="B" label="Last Name" labelTooltip="Last Name">
          <fb:control>
            <Input type="Text" id="lname"/>
          </fb:control>
        </fb:FilterGroupItem>
        <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" id="department1" groupTitle="Group1" name="C" label="Department" labelTooltip="Department">
          <fb:control>
            <Input type="Text" id="department"/>
          </fb:control>
        </fb:FilterGroupItem>
      </fb:filterGroupItems>

      </fb:FilterBar>

      <Table id="idF4" inset="true"
        backgroundDesign="Translucent"
        visibleRowCount="5"
        noDataText="No data exists" >
        <headerToolbar>
          <Toolbar>
            <Label text="User(s)"></Label>
          </Toolbar>
        </headerToolbar>
        <columns>
          <Column>
            <Text text="User" type="Navigation"/>
          </Column>
          <Column minScreenWidth="small" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
            <Text text="First Name" type="Navigation" />
          </Column>
          <Column minScreenWidth="small" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
            <Text text="Last Name" type="Navigation" />
          </Column>
          <Column>
            <Text text="Department" type="Navigation"/>
          </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
          <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" selected="true" press="handleLineItemPress">
            <cells>
              <Text />
              <Text />
              <Text />
              <Text "/>
            </cells>
          </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
      </Table>
    </content>
    <beginButton>
      <Button text="Cancel" press="onCloseDialog" />
    </beginButton>
  </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I am not dynamically binding the data. But instead following the below approach.

for ( var i = 0; i < oData.results.length; i++) {

```
                             oEntry.Bname = oData.results[i].Bname;
                             oEntry.Name1 = oData.results[i].Name1;
                             oEntry.Name2 = oData.results[i].Name2;
                             oEntry.Department = oData.results[i].Department;

                             var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem(
                             {
                               cells : [
                                   new sap.m.Text({
                                     text : oEntry.Bname
                                   }),
                                   new sap.m.Text({
                                     text : oEntry.Name1
                                   }),
                                   new sap.m.Text({
                                     text : oEntry.Name2
                                   }),
                                   new sap.m.Text({
                                     text : oEntry.Department
                                   }) ] } );

                             oTable.addItem(oTemplate);

                             }
```

Now when I select an entry from this table, the event "press" is not trigerred.

I have a controller code also.

```
  handleLineItemPress : function(oEvent){
                              var currentRowContext = oEvent.getParameter("rowContext");

                              },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really?....

Just take a good look at your code first.

You have defined a table -- without databinding -- so it just has one `ColumnListItem` with a `press` event assigned.

In your code, you are adding more `ColumnListItem`'s to your table, and these don't have a `press` event assigned.

And now you're asking why the `press` event for those rows isn't working? ;-)

*(On a side note, what's the reasoning why you aren't using data binding?)*